# Why is mass changed for moment of inertia in the formula for rotational kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

The linear kinetic energy is

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot v^2$$

and the rotational kinetic energy is

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot I \cdot \omega^2$$

Why is mass changed for moment of inertia in the equation for rotational kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a changed formula or a different type of kinetic energy. It's just that for a rigid object about a fixed axis, individual particles constituting the object are moving through space, and posess a translational kinetic energy.

---

The rotational kinetic energy is the *sum* of the translational kinetic energies of each of the individual constituent particles of infinitesimal mass $dm$:

[image]

$$dK = \frac{1}{2} (dm) v^2 = \frac{1}{2} (dm) (r\omega)^2$$
$$dK = \frac{1}{2}\omega^2.(r^2dm)$$
$$\int dK =\frac{1}{2}\omega^2.(\int r^2.dm)$$
$$\boxed{K_R = \frac{1}{2}\omega^2.I}$$

Hope this helps.

---

[Image source](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Dourmashkin)/16%3A_Two_Dimensional_Rotational_Kinematics/16.03%3A_Rotational_Kinetic_Energy_and_Moment_of_Inertia)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is mass changed for moment of inertia in the equation for rotational kinetic energy?

The equation for rotational kinetic energy is actually derived from the equation for translational (linear) kinetic energy. Imagine a particle of mass $m$ rotating at constant distance $r$ and speed $v$ about some axis. Its kinetic energy is

$$K = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$$

Since distance does not change then

$$v = \frac{C}{T} = \frac{2\pi r}{T} = (2 \pi f) r = \omega r$$

where $C$ is the circle (path) circumference, $T$ and $f$ are the rotation period and frequency, and $\omega$ is the angular speed. With $v = \omega r$ the equation for kinetic energy can be written as

$$K = \frac{1}{2} (m r^2) \omega^2$$

Now imagine a **rigid body** with $n$ particles rotating about some axis. Since they are considered to be part of the rigid body, their distance $r$ to the axis of rotation does not change and they all have the same angular velocity $\omega$. The total kinetic energy of the rotating rigid body is then

$$K = \frac{1}{2} (m_1 r_1^2) \omega^2 + \frac{1}{2} (m_2 r_2^2) \omega^2 + \dots = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i} (m_i r_i^2) \omega^2 = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2$$

If the rigid body is a *continuous distribution of mass*, which is usually the case, it cannot be represented by a finite number of particles. In this case the sum becomes an integral

$$I = \int r^2 dm$$

In a more complex motion of a rigid body which includes both translational and rotational motion, the rigid-body motion can always be divided into translation of the center of mass and rotation about the center of mass. In this case the total total kinetic energy of the rigid body is

$$K = \frac{1}{2} m v_\text{cm}^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_\text{cm} \omega^2$$

where $v_\text{cm}$ is the translational speed of the center of mass, and $I_\text{cm}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of mass.